# PayPal sandbox error after logging in from another application

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a test website from where I'm redirecting to paypal sandbox account , to complete my transaction. Till some days it was working fine. But from today when I redirect to sandbox account, it gives me below error

Error -
If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.

If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.

If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
UserException: message 'An id of zero was passed to PartyPostalAddressPBImpl::load_by_id', return code: 3505 Backtrace: PPException::PPException(String const&) User::UserException::UserException(int, String const&) User::PartyPostalAddressPBImpl::load_by_id(unsigned long long) User::AddressPBImpl::load_by_id(unsigned long long, ForUpdate) User::ReputationALIImpl::processReputation(DeprecatedUserShim*, ReputationContainer*, char const*, int, MsgLog2*, DeprecatedUserShim const*) (anonymous namespace)::load_seller_details(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, PimpXClick&, unsigned long&, String&, ReputationContainer*) (anonymous namespace)::load_recipient_info(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, PimpXClick&, MerchantInfoUbiquityContainer&, CreditCardUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, FlowInfoUbiquityContainer&, PassedParametersUbiquityContainer&, String&, ReputationContainer*, WalletInfoContainer*) Rapids::BusinessBlocks::HostedPayments::load_recipient(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, PimpXClick&, MerchantInfoUbiquityContainer&, CreditCardUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, FlowInfoUbiquityContainer&, PassedParametersUbiquityContainer&, String&, WalletInfoContainer*) Rapids::Flows::OneX::StateOneXEC_Start::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String const&, String const&, unsigned long long) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge const*) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_call(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

Is there any issue with the merchant account to whom I pay? Or anything else.

Please assist

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your test Business account. I'm also trying to figure out why it happens. If you want to continue testing, create a new business account in your sandbox.

Dashboard > Sandbox > Accounts > Create Account

Comment: I think this problem occurs when you are using the sandbox with multiple accounts. You could try clearing your cookies, that seems to work.

Comment: I created a new account with paypal, and logged in to developer account with the new account. I registered my app with new secret key and client id, and seems the busines account is automatically registered when we verify our email address. Then tried redirecting to paypal and logged in to developer account through new account and there was no issue seen. the transaction was fine. Now no issue. But out of curiosity I want to ask why did paypal not allow my previous account to work?

Comment: After some analysis what I got is the business accounts which were created earlier or which i was using earlier became invalid or corrupt (which I don't know why :) may be paypal can address) . But after creating another business account for the original paypal account, i needed to associate myapp with that business account and get the new client id and token to put that in my code, and after wards my app worked fine. May be why the previous business account went invalid is a matter of concern as it can happen in live enviornment too